# The number of prime years in a lifetime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

$2013$ is not a prime: $3 \times 11 \times 61$.
I was born in a prime year, and if I live as expected according to the statistics for U.S. males,
I will just reach another prime year, $2027$.  That will encompass $11$ prime years in my lifetime, which
I assume is high (because birth and probable-expiration hit primes directly).

What is the expected number of prime years in a lifetime of length $x$ years,
starting at year $n$?
I am aware that the [Second Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%25E2%2580%2593Littlewood_conjecture) is likely to be false for large $n$,
but does that conjectured relationship, $\pi(x+y) \le \pi(x) + \pi(y)$, 
still yield the best interval estimate for small $n$?

Comment: In addition to the very nice answer from Eric N, change the first occurrence of i in the [**WA Routine**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%7B15%2Bi%2C+2012%2Bi%2CPrimeQ%5B2012+%2B+i%5D%7D%2C%7Bi%2C0%2C200%7D%5D%5D) to "current_age + i", where a is your current age and it will provide your age versus year versus if it is a prime year for the next 200 years. For example, it is currently set to age 15 years old. Live long and prosper! Regards

Comment: are you going to live to 2027 but skip 2017?

Comment: @Jonathan: No, I was counting 2017: ..., 2011, 2017, 2027.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is the expected number of prime years in a lifetime of length $x$ years, starting at
> year $n$?

The exact number will be $\pi(n+x)-\pi(n)$, where $\pi(y)=\sum_{p\leq y}1 $ is the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), but how large do we expect this to be?

The primes are distributed around $n$ with density $\frac{1}{\log n}$, so the expected number would be between $\frac{x}{\log n}$ and $\frac{x}{\log (n+x)}$.  Provided that $n$ is much larger than $x$, this gives $\frac{x}{\log n}$ as the expected number of prime years.  Supposing that a man born in $2000$ lives to the ripe old age of $100$, this estimate gives approximately $13$ primes in their lifetime.  In reality there are $14$ primes between $2000$ and $2100$, which is not far off.

Note however, that if we take $n$ to be very large, it is possible that a person may live to $100$ and never experience a prime year.  Indeed, suppose that an individual was born in the year $K=101!+1$. Then even if they live a long life, and die at $100$ years old, they will  never have experienced a prime year, since each of $101!+2$, $101!+3$, $101!+4$,...,$101!+101$ are composite.

In the opposite direction, the [Brun-Titchmarsh theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%E2%80%93Titchmarsh_theorem) tells us that $$\pi(x+n)-\pi(n)\leq \frac{2x}{\log x},$$ which gives us an upper bound on the number of prime years one can experience.  Even if one were to live to be $200$ years old, they would not see more than $75$ primes, regardless of when they were born.

> **Added:**  The density of the primes, which is $\frac{1}{\log n}$ around $n$, goes to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so unless life expectancy increases over time, the expected number of primes experienced in the average lifetime will converge to zero.  A person born around the year $1$ million A.D. would expect to see only 7 primes if she were to live to $100$.  To achieve the same expected number of primes as a woman born near the year $2000$, she would have to live to $190$.
>
> This can also be used to give a good idea of how slowly $\log x$ grows.  For an individual's expected number of primes to be less than $1$ in their lifetime, they would have to be born past the year $10^{44}$ A.D., and considering that best estimates put the death of the sun at around $4\times 10^9$ A.D., this is very far away.
>
> In fact, for the next $368000$ years, every individual who lives to be $100$ will experience at least one prime year.  However, there is [no prime over a $114$ year period](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html) from $370261$ A.D. to $370365$ A.D., so for the unfortunate individual born in $370261$ A.D., they will experience no prime years unless they live past 114 years old.

Comment: Aside from this being a comprehensive answer, it's nice that in the end you included the opposite question (and answer) as well.

Comment: This answer is worth well more than the question---Thanks, Eric!  And may you see many primes. :-)

Comment: If you are born in the year $101!$, then "if they live a long life" might not equal "$100$ years old". A complete answer should also take into account the increase in life expectancy over the years :)

Comment: You upper bound estimate of $75$ primes seems to be a very conservative estimate. Can we obtain a better estimate using the sieve method for the number of primes one would see over a period of $200$ ? i.e. going upto the prime $13$ can we say that within $200$ consecutive number approximately $$200 (1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/5)(1-1/7)(1-/11)(1-/13) \approx 38$$ are likely to be prime?

Comment: @Marvis: I don't think it is that conservative.  Improving the $2$ in the Brun-Titchmarsh theorem is a long open problem with many implications.  A conjectured stronger version, known as the second [Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) states that $\pi(x+y)\leq \pi(x)+\pi(y)$, and this is believed to be false since it is inconsistent with the [Hardy-Littlewood prime $k$-tuples conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture).

Comment: @Marvis: that estimate is incorrect. Observe that most numbers (6) are divisible by two primes, 2 and 3, and your method counts these as two different numbers, instead of just one number, 6. Also observe that adding more primes to your sieve makes it farther from the original method, instead of closer. You could actually just take the probability of the union of a number being divisible by the kth prime. ($P(A)+P(B)+P(C) -P(A \cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B \cap C)+ P(A \cap B \cap C)$, for three primes, and there are formula for more events.) Here's an estimate using that $n$ with 2, 3: $\frac{2}{3}n$

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams I don't think it counts them twice. for instance, if we want to leave out the multiple of $2$ and $3$, the number of multiple of $2$ or $3$ is given by approximately $200/2 + 200/3 - 200/6 = 200 - 200(1-1/2)(1-1/3)$. Essentially I am just doing what you have said.

Comment: The year $100! + 1$ will likely be long after the [heat death of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe), so I don't think Bob will be too worried about not having any prime-years during his life :)

Comment: @Marvis, You're right, my bad.

Comment: @EricNaslund I was saying that you could obtain a better bound for specific case of $x=200$. A naive argument of even counting just the number of multiple of $2$ or $3$ in a set of $200$ consecutive numbers gives an upper bound of  $200 - \lfloor 200/2 \rfloor - \lfloor 200/3 \rfloor + \lfloor 200/6 \rfloor = 67$ better than the $75$ you have in your answer. (It can be made even better by taking into account multiple of $5$, $7$ etc up-to primes till $200$) or Am I making some trivial mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Marvis: You are definitely right about this, but be careful.  I think the upper bound should have the ceiling of $200/6$.  When I wrote my previous comment, I meant it about about general $x$ and $n$, but for fixed $x$ and much smaller than $n$ we should be able to do better.

Comment: @Marvis: Using the primes $2,3,5,7$, I get an upper bound of $54$, but this does not seem to be improved upon by using $11$ as well.  The problem is that the added terms should be ceilings, while the subtracted terms are floors, and I don't see a clever way around this.